# How to make responsive images and captions get along?

Tags: image, html, css, responsive-design, viewport

In this scenario, images are living up to responsive design, but the **captions are not adjusting along with them**.

Makes sense in the code, but how can it be done without setting a `max-width` in pixel values?

There are are two images in a single `section`, each inside a `figure` with a `figcaption`:

```
<section>    
    <figure>
        <img src="link.jpg">
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="link.png">
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>
```

[In the CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/XjthT/21/), we have set a few things, but most importantly, the `img` have `max-width: 100%` set, but there seems to be no way to make the captions do the same:

[image]

**How can this overlap be avoided in a responsive design with older browsers in mind?** Apart from setting `max-width: 300px` on the `figure` or `section` elements.

Note that any solution should consider that when the window is made smaller, it should allow the image to get smaller:

[image]

In other words, the `auto margins` should be go away. (Horizontal margins would waste space on narrow viewports.)

Answer (score 2):

To bind the `figcaption` to the width of the `img` you'll need to wrap the both of them inside of an element that will collapse to the width of the `img`, in this case I've used a `div`:

```
<figure>
    <div>
        <img src="http://www.phibetaiota.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Google-Data-Center.jpg">
        <figcaption>First example caption</figcaption>
    </div>
</figure>
```

With the CSS:

```
section figure div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XjthT/23/).

You may wish to adjust the `overflow` properties of this `div` and, obviously, adjust to taste. But if you want to keep the `figure` elements as 100% width then you need another element to contain the `img` and `figcaption` in order to constrain the width of the `figcaption` to that of the `img`.

Comment: Thanks David, that makes sense. However, the images are being cut off when the screen is reduced and `overflow` solutions only enable the scroll bars. Also, I added an update to the original question.

Comment: So you want the image itself to shrink, in response to resizing to a smaller viewport?

Comment: Yes. And on a larger viewport, they should not exceed 100% width, neither should captions. (I noticed that the caption, in your fiddle is now offset by a few `px` at the bottom — probably because the div is an `inline-block` right?)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I completely understood what you want to achieve, but is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/XjthT/124/

I added a span around the img and caption:

```
section figure span{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: "Apart from setting `max-width: 300px` on the `figure` or `section` elements"

Comment: @Baumr Oh I'm sorry, didn't see that part. Updated answer with a new method.